# How to merge type of array fields from different types in typescript?

Tags: typescript

I have two types which both of them have a same name field in array with different types. I'd like to merge these two types and the element type, not the array, of the field could be merged too.

I tried such code below but it failed when I was going to do a find/filter on the merged array:

```js
type A = {
  arr: {
    foo: number
  }[]
  other_field: number;
}

type B = {
  arr: {
    bar: string
  }[]
  another_field: string;
}

type C = A & B
/*
what I'm expecting is:
type C = {
  arr: {
    foo: number;
    bar: string;
  }[]
  other_field: number;
  another_field: string;
}
 */

const array: C = { arr: [] }
console.log(array.arr[0].foo) // Valid if access the foo from A
console.log(array.arr[0].bar) // Valid if access the bar from B
array.arr.filter(n => n.foo)  // Valid if access the foo from A in filter
array.arr.filter(n => n.bar)  // Property 'bar' does not exist on type '{ foo: number; }'.(2339)
```

I'm not sure if this `merging` is doable.

Comment: @jcalz I updated the post. Recurse is not necessary but there may be other fields in type A and B. What I want is to merge the fields from both A and B, just like the normal & does, but for array fields I'd like them  to be merged in a different way.

Comment: @jcalz Your sample works for me. Sorry I didn't check it carefully. Would you like to add a detailed answer ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you've noticed, [intersections](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types) of [array types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#arrays) in TypeScript have some poor behaviors.  This is considered a design limitation as described in [microsoft/TypeScript#41874](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/41874) and you'll need to work around it.  If you want an intersection of arrays to acts as a single array type whose element type is an intersection, (i.e., you want `X[] & Y[]` to act like `(X & Y)[]`), then the workaround would be to convert intersections of arrays to arrays of intersections.

---

To perform such a conversion for just the top-level property in a type, you can use a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) like this:

```
type DeIntersectArrayProps<T> =
  { [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends any[] ? T[K][number][] : T[K] };
```

which produces:

```
type C = DeIntersectArrayProps<A & B>;
/* type C = {
    arr: ({
        foo: number;
    } & {
        bar: string;
    })[];
    other_field: number;
    another_field: string;
} */
```

That works because arrays have a numeric [index signature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#index-signatures) of the form `interface Array<T> { [k: number]: T }` and so `(X[] & Y[])[number]` is `X & Y`.

---

If you want a type which does something like that regardless of how deep in an object type the array intersection is, then you need a *recursive* mapped type like:

```
type DeepDeIntersectArrayProps<T> = { [K in keyof T]:
  T[K] extends any[] ?
  DeepDeIntersectArrayProps<T[K][number]>[] :
  DeepDeIntersectArrayProps<T[K]>
};
```

Which produces a type equivalent to

```
type C = DeepDeIntersectArrayProps<A & B>;
/* type C = {
    arr: {
        foo: number;
        bar: string;
    }[];
    other_field: number;
    another_field: string;
} */
```

And you can see that it works at arbitrary depths:

```
type XX = DeepDeIntersectArrayProps<{ x: A } & { x: B }>;
/* type XX = {
    x: {
        arr: {
            foo: number;
            bar: string;
        }[];
        other_field: number;
        another_field: string;
    };
} */
```

---

So those both work for the example provided in the question.  Such type juggling can have unexpected edge-case behavior; be sure to test against your full range of use cases.  For example, if you expect to encounter [`readonly` arrays](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#the-readonlyarray-type), or [tuple types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#tuple-types), you should test with them and see if you can live with the results.  Depending on your needs these utility types may work as written, or they may need to be refactored... but this is probably out of scope for the current question so I'll leave it there.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noErrorTruncation=true#code/C4TwDgpgBAglC8UDeAoKUCGAnLAuZa6UAZgPan4B2ArgLYBGEWhAvgNoC6hpwAFkwH1iASwgAbACZU6jLAG4ULFClCQoAIQQF02PNqL1s+AM7AswygHNWnQhko9+WIaMkmzFywqUrw0ACIQAJKUwEzGEADGwDA4GCAAClikYMYAPAAqAHwIhEhQbADSUBZQANYQIKTEUBkc+BlFHFAQAB5hlBLGmJQgnFAA-LVNbDQMTBz9DU1QLAqq0ADCWoEhYVgR0bFY8Ukp6XAAZBpZCgD0AFRQC1DLiKhEmDj4ABQPj0RkFFBjsgqPLCgx3eHyghj0pnMVn+RBYAEpODD0I5BCJxFIfjImEieijnGi3FBIZ5vFALmdlL41IEIGBVqFwlEYnFEslUpkcvcCsVShUqjU6rhCI1Cs02h0uj0+s0BoQaXTggyNkztrs2ekRZNfhMslM5RBafT1ptmTtWftMk0sooFFSlncoPKjYytiy9uyjidzlcbg6QU89P7Hl9pON5IRQeD3FCvBHZoi43iXOjQ384-YkwSMcToYoyRS7VAABpFlYGhVrF2mtUW-KtfBwQHAqD1jSzU4oS7XPzF0v3OOtoNEXT4IegkOYsM40HoKNEjy5mfxjjToiZ1wY7XhpcZviojfRklxuZ58mUlBAA)

Comment: I followed the link you provided and found another issue you mentioned at https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/39693. It that the same issue as my question? Is this a compiler limitation?

Comment: It's another problem with array intersections, but not the exact one you're asking about (it's about `for` loops, not about using `filter()` method).  The general problem is that arrays of intersections have very strange behavior and there's not much they can do to fix it directly.

Comment: CMIIW. The magic of the solution is about this `T[K][number][]` expression? It looks like you decompose an array and then compose it again inplace and that leads to an expected type intersection.

Comment: Yes.  Relevant portion of answer: "Arrays have a numeric index signature of the form `interface Array<T> { [k: number]: T }` and so `(X[] & Y[])[number]` is `X & Y`."

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to create an `IntersectableArray<T>`:

```js
interface IntersectableArray<T> {
  [n : number]: T;
  filter: (p: (x: this[number]) => unknown) => IntersectableArray<this[number]>;
  // ...
}
```

This is similar to `T[]` or `Array<T>` but uses `this[number]` in the type of `filter`, which uses [polymorphic this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#polymorphic-this-types) to fix the type of filter.

It can be used before calling `filter`:

```js
function deintersect<T>(array: T[]): IntersectableArray<T> {
  return array;
}

deintersect(array.arr).filter(n => n.foo)
deintersect(array.arr).filter(n => n.bar)

(array.arr as IntersectableArray<T>).filter(n => n.bar)
```

Or as part of your types:

```js
type A = {
  arr: IntersectableArray<{
    foo: number
  }>
  other_field?: number;
}

type B = {
  arr: IntersectableArray<{
    bar: string
  }>
  another_field?: string;
}

type C = A & B

const array: C = { arr: [{foo:1, bar:"a"}] }

array.arr.filter(n => n.foo) 
array.arr.filter(n => n.bar)
```

Comment: Interesting. Would you like to add some detail explanations about how does this interface work?